# Im trying to change the background of a CSS "body" property with JS...I keep getting a console error of "newBgColor is not defined"

Tags: javascript, css, function, dom

I have been trying to use a function to change a background color with DOM. I'm probably missing something super "in my face" but I can't see it

My JS code is -

```
function changeBg()     {     
let newBgColor = document.querySelector("body")      
console.log(newBgColor)      
newBgColor.style.backgroundColor = "white";      
}
```

```
The CSS Im hoping to change is -

     body {      
  font-family: 'Open Sans';     
  font-weight: normal;      
  max-width: 760px;      
  background-color: #ffe8d6;      
  margin: 0 auto;      
  color: rgb(193, 178, 164);      

  }
``   
I keep getting this error -
ReferenceError - newBgColor is not defined.
```

Comment: What is the actual error message? That error does not seem possible with the code you have shown us.

Comment: That code won't produce that error, not even if (as Teemu suggested) you were running the code before the `body` was in the DOM. You'd get a different error in that case, but not the one you've quoted.

Comment: @epascarello - It's in the title and also hidden at the end of the code block: `ReferenceError - newBgColor is not defined` (Which is the exact error V8 would give if you tried to use an undeclared variable...but as you say, the code above won't produce that error.)

Comment: 1. you can use `document.body` 2. you're using a variable called "newBgColor" but that name does not make any sense at all 3. that script is in your <head> most likely, meaning it runs before <body> exists and therefore `document.querySelector("body")` is undefined 4. how and when are you calling the function? My guess is you have `<body onload="newBgColor()">` or something, which again, does not make any sense, given that the function is called "beigeBg" despite setting the background color to "white", which also cannot be noticed since it's the default

Comment: Kiitos Teemu. Thank you all for the kind responses. Im running through browser console to see if it works and getting that error

Comment: Here's the proper, working way to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/2ykefzL6/

Comment: Thank you the answer provided helped but I also realized that as I had moved my CSS and js into separate sheets that some code was running first as @T.J. Crowder alluded to was the main problem so when I moved everything back it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what you could do, load the CSS in the `<head>` and load the JavaScript at the end of the page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Body Bg Color</title>

  <style>
    body {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-weight: normal;
      max-width: 760px;
      background-color: #ffe8d6;
      margin: 0 auto;
      color: rgb(193, 178, 164);
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>


  <script>
    function beigeBg() {
      let newBgColor = document.querySelector("body")
      console.log(newBgColor)
      newBgColor.style.backgroundColor = "beige";
    }

    beigeBg();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try moving your `<script>` tags into the head... it also works.

Comment: Yep I had made the mistake of having it work and then moving things to separate sheets and then it didn't work ...as soon as I moved it back into one sheet it worked so thanks for the help all.

Comment: Yes, absolutely; very much yes